# Google Sheets replaceText() Equivalent

Tags: scripting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

In Google Sheets I have a column of cells, example below, which contains useful data - and some junk leftover from the source it came from. Basically I'm trying to write a script to remove "tag×" and anything that comes after it. I'm only interested in keeping the names

**adam smith tag× production×**
**bill jones tag× sales×**
**chris pants tag× warehouse×**
**dave watts tag× phones×**

I can do this in Excel with by looping through the column with
**Selection.Replace What:="tag×*", Replacement:=""**

But in my new office we're using Google Sheets. I thought I could do this with replaceText() but that function seems only available on the text class of the Document Service. I looked through the Spreadsheet App classes but can't find anything. Does anyone know if this kind of function exists in the Spreadsheet App, or how I could process this kind of column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use string manipulation.

Get all data in the column into an array and iterate row by row doing the string reduction.
code below

```
function removeTags(){
  var column = 1
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getRange(1,column,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  for(var n in data){
    if(data[n][0]==''){continue};// if cell empty then continue
    var str = data[n][0].toString();
    data[n][0]= str.substring(0,str.indexOf('tag'));//remove everything after "tag"
  }
  sh.getRange(1,column,sh.getLastRow(),1).setValues(data);// update sheet with new data
}
```

Comment: I've inserted the code and it works perfectly. substring() is the exact function I needed. I've been unable to find documentation on that in developers.google. Thank you so much for making it clear.

Comment: Glad to hear it ;) don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: This is plain JavaScript,you'll find all the JS methods on the internet... w3school for example.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could so easily call JS functions from within a Google Apps Script, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Not fancy but assuming they were all structured like you demonstrated it could be done with two functions. Assuming your data is in column A2 and these functions are in b2 and c2 respectively. A working example is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V6F60dmbDcfgYERAYbP3lSn0ZRyt28cqQZGcCZ_CwfA/edit#gid=0).

=find("tag×",a2) 
=left(a2, b2-2)

Answer (score 0):

Create a column with this formula:

> =left(A1,find("tag×",A1)-2)

Drag down adjacent to the column with the original data.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBJ03.png)

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXEXTRACT` is another alternative, try this

`=Arrayformula(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(^\w+\ \w+)")))`

[REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)

[image: result]